# Traceback StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, iis-7

I've got an Umbraco site using a fair ammount of usercontrols in which, somewhere - somehow, a stackoverflow exception gets thrown every now and then.
Since the SOE doesn't occur when testing is has something to do with a user posting or getting some information (fair enough: something I've missed).

How can I trace back where my stackoverflow exception took place inside my code? Are there tools available to check my sources to see if I've missed some recursive method? Or how can I debug the running process?

Comment: Logging logging logging.

Comment: IIS extended Log, db-call logging,  eventviewers .. the works - just can't seem to pinpoint the where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that **debugging** the application (sometimes having to attach VS to the correct `w3wp.exe` process) and setting VS to **break on exception** is the most helpful. You could still see the stack trace which is full of the same series of method calls.

Comment: On the development machine - this works, and wooohooo, I finally found the culprit.. due to a condition which only could occur during full moon in a leap year with a user created over three years ago a certain page would call three other pages which would call the first page again... (glad I've got it sorted!)

Answer (score 0):

If the application crashes, enable this registry setting to create a crashdump for all crashing apps:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps]
    "DumpFolder"="C:\\TEMP"
    "DumpCount"=dword:00000010
    "DumpType"=dword:00000002
```

It will create a crash dump in your C:\Temp folder. Either open this dump file in a newer version of Visual Studio which will show you the exact code it crashed (just like if you where debugging and you got an unhandled exception).

Or an extremely useful MS tool for all your dump analysis needs: Debug Diagnostics Tools (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924). Video walkthrough here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-123-DebugDiag-Part-3

This will analyse your crashed application and show you all the threads and their managed and unmanaged stacktraces.
It will likely point out exactly the issue of your crash and where it occurred so you can check that stacktrace.

If however the program did not crash, you can open task manager and rightclick the process and create a dump file manually. Sending this dump file through Debug Diagnostics on a crash analysis it will show you the last X exceptions that did occur in your application with stacktraces. I use this method to find the actual error of user applications when the user gets a nice simplified error message. As an alternative to creating a dump from taskmanager you can also use procdump.exe or Debug Diagnostics itself to create rules on when to create dump files.

I really believe more people should be aware of how incredible easy a DUMP file together with Debug Diagnostics is to find any error that occurred in a production environment, where we don't have our handy development tools available.